# How do I Relate these 4 Tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

Trying to setup a simple Thread/Poll table mapping.

Here is what I have:

**Threads** table

- ThreadID (Primary Key/Identity Column)

**Polls** table

- PollID (Primary Key, FK for ThreadID for one-to-one relation)
- Question

**PollOptions** table

- PollOptionID (Identity/Primary Key)
- Text
- PollID

**PollVotes** table

- PollVoteID (Primary Key/Identity)
- PollOptionID

I'm not sure if this is a proper relationship. It seems wrong but I'm not sure whats wrong with it.

A **Thread** can have **0 or 1 Poll**.

A **Poll** can have **2 or more PollOptions**.

A **PollOption** can have **0 or many PollVotes**.

I'm going to be using Entity Framework and before I generate the code for it (VS 2010, .NET 4) I want to make sure I have the proper relationship mapping.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your relationship mapping, though maybe give some thought to adding a spot in the PollVotes table to mapping to user IDs.

Comment: Yeah I have that, but I just chose to omit for brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misreading your relation there, but it seems like relating Poll to Thread would make more sense than Thread to Poll, since you have a 0 or 1 relationship with Thread to Poll. Otherwise I think your relationships look fine.

Comment: But a Poll is a child of Thread (somewhat). A Poll can only be created for a Thread, a thread can be created without a poll.

Comment: Right, which is why the Poll should hold the ID to the Thread. Eg:
Thread Table:
ThreadId

Poll Table:
PollId
ThreadId